# Add a Windows Service as a dependency to a .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

A Windows Service can specify that it depends on another second service. When the system will try to start the (first) service, it will see that it depends on the second one and start it (the second one) first.

Can the same thing be done for an application? I want the system to start a certain service (if it's not started yet) when my application starts.

I can't just call it from my app because my app runs without admin privileges, while the service runs as Local System. The service has already been installed on the computer.

<sub>(I know I can have the system auto start the service. Unfortunately, there's a problem with .net **Services**. They can only *reliably* be started with delayed start, and my app needs to be available immediately.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When your app starts, just check if the service is started

[ServiceController Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a Windows service and allows you to connect to a running or
>   stopped service, manipulate it, or get information about it.

A totally untested example

```
// Check whether the service is started.
ServiceController sc  = new ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "MyAwesomeService";
Console.WriteLine("The MyAwesomeService status is currently set to {0}", 
                   sc.Status.ToString());

if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
   // Start the service if the current status is stopped.
   Console.WriteLine("Starting MyAwesomeService...");
   try 
   {
      // Start the service, and wait until its status is "Running".
      sc.Start();
      sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

      // Display the current service status.
      Console.WriteLine("The MyAwesomeService is now set to {0}.", 
                         sc.Status.ToString());
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Could not start the MyAwesomeService.");
   }
}
```

**Update**

ServiceController will use the current thread's principal to make the registry and service control manager calls and you have to make sure it is set to an admin user if you want to manipulate the services.

you can either impersonate user, or add more fine grain permission to let your uses start and stop it, or force your app to start in admin privileges

[Give user permission to start/stop ONE service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2d4cc5ad-ea0c-494b-b4b0-abc06eda1c5b/give-user-permission-to-startstop-one-service?forum=itproxpsp)

[WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Access denied. As I said, the app runs non admin.

Comment: @ispiro this should get you pointed in the right direction, otherwise you are out of luck, ie you will need to have permission to start and stop it. or you will need to auto start it with windows

Comment: How does this point me in the right direction if the question already ruled out your answer? Besides, your answer doesn't even answer the question. If your answer is "it can't be done." say so. And if so, a source would be welcome. All your "answer" did was waste my time trying to start the service from the app, assuming that I made a mistake thinking it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the same thing be done for an application?

No, there's no way to do this.

> I want the system to start a certain service (if it's not started yet)
>   when my application starts

So, make the service auto start/auto start delayed (depending on your preferences).

> Unfortunately, there's a problem with .net services. They can only
>   reliably be started with delayed start

Service auto start doesn't mean, that service will be started, when your application need it. Application can start before service with auto start.

Moreover, even if service is started from the point of operating system, it doesn't mean, that it has finished initialization.

The only *reliable* way to achieve what you want is to communicate from application to service, e.g. query some data from the service, obtain a synchronization object, etc. Then, if the service is available, application continues. Otherwise, depending on application, it either waits some time and tries to communicate again, or quits.

Comment: Thanks. Your first sentence does answer the question now. I'm not accepting yet, though, to see if someone comes around with an answer showing it can be done after all. Thanks again.